# Unknown ZAP spider url result

Tags: zap

I'm new to security and have some weird result when I spidering my own website. Below are my url result for OWASP ZAP spidering on my website

[image]

I'm wondering what are the red circle url with OUT_OF_SCOPE flag? I never put all these url into my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are URLs that ZAP found on your site.
However as they are on different domains (ie OUT_OF_SCOPE) ZAP did not spider them.
If you want to know where ZAP found them you can try using the Search tab :)